# Is sex haram or not

Tags: islamic-basis

I am not married but I am questioning if sex is haram or not in the Islam. I have not anyone yet except a sheikh and he told that I wasn’t so I curios so I decided to ask. I am new to the Islam so I don’t know anything

Comment: The fact that you are new to Islam doesn't mean you can't do a simple search, to me this is a kind of missed homework question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seems like a missed homework question., The matter is easily googlable!

Comment: Sex with whom exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Sex is absolutely allowed (Halaal) and not haram in Islam. Because without sex the human race will cease to reproduce and perish from the planet.

As always though a few rules apply:

1. Sexual intercourse must happen between a male and a female
2. Sex while fasting is not allowed.
3. Sexual intercourse during menstruation is not allowed.
4. The female involved during sex should either be a wife or a concubine.
5. If the female is a concubine, the male should be a sole owner/master of the female and she must have been obtained during war as war booty from the enemy or bought as a slave or obtained in the shape of a gift from another owner.
6. If the female is a wife, she needs to meet a few conditions. For example: courtship is not allowed If a female bears one of the following relationship with the male:

> Mother, daughter, sister, father's sister, mother's sister,
>       brother's daughters, sister's daughters, son's wife, mothers who had
>       breastfed, foster sisters, mother-in-law, and step-daughter under
>       guardianship born to your wife from another man while you and her mother (your wife)
>       has already done sex with each other. Furthermore, taking in marriage two sisters
>       simultaneously is also not allowed.

The same rules apply to a female the other way around.

The source of my answer is from Quran chaptor 4 as its explained in greater detail from verses 20 to 30.

Hope that's the answer to your question.

Comment: *"Sex is absolutely allowed (Halaal) and not haram in Islam."* I think you should rephrase this. If someone don't read your answer fully, one will easily misunderstand

Comment: Good point @Kilise. However, Islam is not about reading partial scripts here and there... In my opinion...if someone can't bother to read... they don't deserve to be enlightened with knowledge.

Comment: @QaisarKhan I don’t understand the reason for the prohibition that applies to “foster sisters”, “mother-in-law” and “ step daughter”. I’m asking because, they do not make part from your own blood, but they are only from another family which is not from yours, so it is like they are strangers to you. So, why it is? Here is what I don’t understand. Can you explain the reasons that the prohibition applies to what I mentioned above? But the rest, I do understand and makes sense.

Comment: @AlexA... Apparently, there are lots of things that simply doesn't make sense. 
Religion itself for example: The grand scheme of God to create the universe and put creatures in it and then giving only humans a dominion over others.. Giving us a freewill and a lust to commit sin but simultaneously commanding us to refrain from doing sin.
Philosophically it doesn't matter to God if he put the entire human race directly in heaven rather than sending them to earth to test them let alone he already know the results.
However, my argument is: Are we in a position to ask Why? from God?

Comment: @QaisarKhan Of course not. I just need some clarification only

Comment: @AlexA regarding the point... what makes sense and what not when it comes to doing sex with blood relatives... its only a matter of how you are being raised. Muslims are thought they cannot have sex with their sisters but they can with their cousins even though both are blood relatives. Adam and Eve who are considered muslims by muslims.. brought their kids to commit incest and they didn't found that offensive.. Because that's how they were raised..Christians on the other hand find it offensive to marry their cousins, because that's not how they are brought up. so agian.. does this make sense?

Comment: @QaisarKhan ... well, uhh, I don’t know... I suppose that as long as God decides that way to be then it is indeed a lot of sense and logic.

Comment: @AlexA. Of course...Therefore, the conclusion is... we don't get to decide what makes sense and what doesn't... we really don't have any privileges to change God's polices... We only have the option to either accept or reject... and based on our decisions and deeds, we will be judged in the hereafter...

Comment: @QaisarKhan Ok, I understand now.

Comment: @QaisarKhan cousin with cousin, thats mean, any cousins of yours? Because, I have another cousin but with grade 3. I don’t know how to explain this logic, but maybe you know what I’m trying to say, right?

Comment: I do...First cousins, second cousins, and third cousins... all are eligible to have sex with.